# Determine the characteristic of R[X]/I.

Tags: ring-theory

Let I be the ideal in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ generated by $p(X)=X^2+2X+3$.

Determine the characteristic of $\mathbb{R}[X]/I$

Am I right in saying the answer is zero as $m(1+I) = m(1)+I \neq 0 $ $\forall m>0$?

Comment: You're staying a statement holds for all $n>0$, but there's no $n$ in the statement; and there's an undefined $m$

Comment: @Max sorry, that was a typo, it should have been m. And I think you knew that...

Comment: Well it looked like a function rather than a multiplication (because of the "$m(1)$" notation, which is clearly uncommon), hence the confusion. But then you still need to justify that $m+I\neq I$

Comment: You have to give an argument why $m\not\in I$ for any $m>0$.